# Wordpress WP-Mail Function

Tags: wordpress, smtp

I have created a email ID, installed WP-SMTP Plugin, configured it correctly, I even test the Function WP-Mail Function, and found out that it is not working.

I replaced it with a new copy hoping that it would work.

From my testing I have found out the following things:

1) When I use "Send all WordPress emails via SMTP. " I am unable to send test mail.

2) When I use "  the PHP mail() function to send emails. " I am able to send test mail but don't receive any thing at the test email ID.

Any one have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Wordpress internal email, I suggest not to do that, for many reasons.

1. The email, will overload your server.
2. The email will (probably) not hit the default folder of the receiver email.
3. If you send many emails (~1000) per day, you can be banned from sending emails.

I suggest you to use special platform for email delivery, that solve the 3 problems above.

Comment: thank you StevenV for the answer, but I am not using internal email, i am using hosting email, I even tried configuring zoho mail, but still the sae problem.

Comment: I set the setting of SMTP of hosting email, now I am able to send mail from website only to admin but not to the client.

Comment: What's is the purpose of the email? transactional? marketing?. In any case, it's better to send from special providers an not from the cPanel

Comment: it is just for the reply for the customer as a reply back form contact us form. either way how to fix WP-MAIL function??

Comment: As i mentioned, just with the sengrid plugin, you can replace that function, and will send email through their servers.